# Is there such a thing as Global SQL Server Custom Properties?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am looking to hold some config key/value style properties on a SQL Server database instance.

The use case is multiple customer databases which all need some configuration settings to run SP's. These settings are unique per instance but we are running many customer databases on a single instance.

I would like to avoid querying a "master" database as this would require holding a named reference to a "master" database.

Looking for something like an ini, properties file etc. that exposes these in SQL Server.

Comment: Keep the settings in your distinct database, I'm not sure why it's a problem to hold a named reference to it?

Comment: Create a single database with a specific name with the per server instance data?  Something like ThisSrvMetaDataDb  .      You should walk though some dev/stage/prod scenarios in your head before you go all in on this.   Also one reason to do this is to use  aliases.

Comment: My main concern about referencing a master is that each customer database needs it's own reference to a master, if that customer database moves to a different instance it would need to point to that instances master. I suppose naming convention is ok here but I am just worried about hard coded strings to "MyMaster" especially for dev/staging environments.